# How RTSP stream can be loaded to an HTML5 player to support multiple OS and browsers?

Tags: html5-video, rtsp, video.js

I am trying to play an rtsp format url in browser .i used video js to do it. But i cant play it or the browser is not streaming it.

I tested in IE,Chrome, and Firefox.

Could you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: RTSP does not work in a browser. You need to provide the video stream in an HTML5 compatible video format. Period.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585002/how-to-avoid-video-js-plays-m3u8-files-on-flash-player-in-safari